# Inserting decimal values from datagridview to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to insert data from datagridview to SQL Server.

The problem is that in my datagridview, I have decimal values with max 18 number after `,` and it's only inserting in the database the values with 0 after `,` .

I've tried to convert the value in my datagridview to decimal but that's not working:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value)
```

I also tried `DefaultCellStyle.Format` and also is not working.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["solde"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Comment: what is the datatype if the column in the table that you are saving it in ?

Comment: And also show us the code you use to save it into the table

Comment: And last but not least, a `,` looks like a regional problem to me, the database actually expects it to be the decimal separator but how you see it on the screen depends on your regional settings

Comment: What is the `DataSource` of your DGV? Why are you trying to get data from a Control? The UI Interface should be used for presentation and to accept User input, which is then validated before it's sent to the source of data, which is then used to update the database. The Types of data source match the database Types. -- A `Decimal` Type doesn't have *commas* or *dots*, those are used in a localized presentation of the data. Don't confuse or mix the data presentation / formatting with the actual value.

Comment: You should also explain "not working". What does that mean? Are you getting error messages? Is the data incorrect? Is the data not getting inserted at all?

Comment: @GuidoG my input data is an excel file with 2 columns.

Comment: @GuidoG This is my code to insert in the database from datagridview :
SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[C9_V] ([C9],[V],[OID],[USERMODIF]) VALUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "', '" + textBox1f2.Text + "', '" + user + "')", conn);
cc.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @SeanLange i am not getting error messages. The problem is in my input data i have decimal values like 300,00 and 46,52 and it's only inserting data with 0 after the commas. The type of column in my database is decimal(38,18).

Comment: @houssemeddineayari You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73123239/edit) your question and put any relevant and important information in the question, not in comments. Nobody will read thru all the comments to get all the information

Comment: Based on the comments you desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. What you posted is wide open to sql injection. This is actually far more important than your task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes a bit difficult to tell what is wrong with your code based on what you write.
The last way you have mention(`dataGridView1.Columns["solde"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";`), looks good. Then there may be a different problem than what you may be aware of. *Can you post your code so that we can help you further with your problem?*

Comment: This is my code to insert in the database from datagridview :
SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[C9_V] ([C9],[V],[OID],[USERMODIF]) VALUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "', '" + textBox1f2.Text + "', '" + user + "')", conn);
cc.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @houssemeddineayari You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73123239/edit) your question and put any relevant and important information in the question, not in comments. Nobody will read thru all the comments to get all the information